# I am able to run code by code runner in VSC. What shall I do?

Tags: visual-studio, vscode-code-runner

I am not able to run the code runner in VSC (Visual studio Code).

Comment: What's the problem? Any errors, what have you tried, etc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.